# How do I get the most recent / official code and jars for siddhi?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I see there's a separate maven repo at http://dist.wso2.org/maven2 but the version of siddhi - your CEP does not match what is in here: https://github.com/wso2/product-cep

Which is current and which can be used? Also, the website has a lead-capture form. Is the product truly apache2 open source or is it in name only?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 products are 100% apache 2.0 license compatible free and open source products. you can find the [siddhi](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi) version used in [WSO2 CEP](https://github.com/wso2/product-cep).
Based on the description given on Siddhi repository,current version is 3.0.2. Please find the [maven nexus repository for Siddhi](http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/siddhi/)